# hibernate query: how to put restrictions on set

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a class that references a set of another class. Something like this:

```
Class A {
    int id;
    Set<Class B> setOfClassB;
}
```

Now when I am writing HbDAO for this class, I have a query which says, bring all records of class A only if one of class B in the sets have a particular condition.

So for eg say that class B has a id and a name. So the query says that bring all the records of class A which contains atleast one B which has the id=1234 and name="somename".

Usually if the set would have been only of some inbuilt variable like int, or string, I would have written a query like this:

```
from A.class.getName() aliasOfA where :someID in elements(aliasOfA.setOfClassB);
```

But now that there is a class, I cannot write a query like this:

```
from A.class.getName() aliasOfA where :someID in elements(aliasOfA.setOfClassB.name);
```

What is right query for this case ?

From my point here's a possible solutions to this:

1. Do it programatically. Bring the set and search the set using a loop and discard the values that do not qualify.

But I do not want to do it this way. I want to instruct the HQL to do this. Also I do not want to write pure SQL query because then I would have to do a lot of joins on this one.
These are my last resorts.

PS: I searched Google but couldn't find anything useful. Its mostly because I do not understand how to put this question in proper words. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a join:

```
select distinct a from A a
inner join a.setOfClassB b
where b.id = 1234 and b.name = 'somename'
```